# Adsense not showing in webview

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, windows-phone

Hi i am developing a windows phone 8 app in C# when i use web browser it doesn't show any Adsense ads I've tried several pages but if i use internet explorer it shows them fine. i can't seem to figure out if its supposed to do that of if its just something i have done wrong.

This is the code i am using for the web browser.

```
 webad1.Navigate(new Uri("http://xxxxxxxx.co.uk/mobile/"));
```

Thanks any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Are you really using both windows phone 8 and windows phone 7? You need to tag it appropriately so people can find what they are looking for. Also you need to post more code. This doesn't tell us anything.

Comment: Did you set the Property "IsScriptEnabled" of the BrowserControl to true?

Comment: no i didn't set isSciptEnabled how do i go about doing that?